# Targeting specific version of application

Tags: c++

Not sure if this question has already been asked or I didn't know the correct wordings to search but basically I want to be able to use a specific version of my application and disable all other features that have been added in a newer version.

For example I currently have version 1.4 of a application I created but I only want to use features available in V1.2 and make it so that I cannot use any features which have been added since, e.g. 1.3?

An example of this is GLSL, you set a specific version upon writing it, and you can't use any features from a higher version than what you assigned.

Is this possible, and if so how to approach it?

Comment: GLSL is a language specification, not an application

Comment: If the "vague idea" is enough, why don't you implement it?    Seriously, you need to set up some logic in your program that represents program version numbers (e.g. a major and minor version), and compares version numbers.   Then you need to provide some data (e.g. in a configuration file) indicating what version the user is authorised to run.   Then, when implementing new functionality, do a test of the form `if (authorised_version < version_with_this_functionality)` and not execute the new functionality unless authorised.

Comment: How is this behaving on bug fixes? Should the 1.4 running as 1.2 reproduce the 1.2 bugs fixed in 1.3? I have never tried such a thing but you could also use inheritance, for example: MyActionv12 contains the 1.2 code which is then extended (and overridden for bugs) in MyActionv13. Then in your main code you have a factory instantiating the correct class based on you current and enforced versions. It seems to me this will lead to very messy code so probably you limit it to some part of the app only? How is GLSL doing it?

Comment: @bolov what i am writing is kind of like like a .INI kind of language.

Comment: @Peter I already have a version check in place. i assume what you are saying is i should just surround new code within if statements or defines ? I guess that should should, thanks.

Comment: @urban hmm... i guess things solved in a newer version would not be reproduced if using a older version.